# List events based on date and time

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm

i'm wondering if someone can help me out with this one

I have the following query :

```
SELECT * FROM `E935308` WHERE date BETWEEN '2015-09-03' AND '2015-09-03' ORDER BY date, time, id
```

The result would be like this:

```
date        time    event
2015-09-03  23327   4
2015-09-03  23402   5
2015-09-03  23434   4
2015-09-03  23991   5
2015-09-03  24030   4
2015-09-03  24195   45
2015-09-03  24210   5
2015-09-03  24627   4
2015-09-03  24634   5
2015-09-03  26348   4
2015-09-03  26370   46
2015-09-03  27152   5
2015-09-03  28407   4
2015-09-03  28408   5
2015-09-03  29856   4
2015-09-03  30428   45
2015-09-03  30449   46
2015-09-03  30514   45
2015-09-03  30540   46
2015-09-03  30555   45
2015-09-03  30617   46
2015-09-03  30631   45
```

There are four events (4, 5, 45 and 46)
Assuming that : 4 = START, 5 = STOP, 45 = IN and 46 = OUT

I need an algorithm to show me the time of the very first event number 4, and after that the time of the first 45 after 4 and 46 that comes right after 45 and at last the first 5 after event 46.

Here is a working example:

```
2015-09-03  23327   24195   26370   27152
2015-09-03  28407   30428   30449   -
2015-09-03  28407   30514   30540   -
```

the dash means event 5 doesn't exist.

I don't know if this is possible, still worth asking for.

Thanks for the help.

EDIT:

To make it a little bit clear, how to eliminate the numbers that are not in brackets?

```
[4]
5
4
5
4
[45]
5
4
5
4
[46]
[5]
4
5
```

Comment: Are those 'times' seconds from midnight?

Comment: MySQL allows a lot of tricks, so I think I'll get a solution in a few minutes

Comment: ok, completely replaced misunderstood first version. I would not call it a "very nice code" since not everyone will see immediately what it does, but it will be much faster inside MySQL than fetching all into php and doing the logic there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: first solution was wrong.

There could be more elegant solutions, but here with only 4 events you can get it in a single scan with 5 variables.

This solution dies when you have joins, so if so you must encapsulate all the joins and orders in an inner subselect, so that the variables-magic just happens on a clear single ordered stream of data. All the queries must be sent in the same SQL Connection, otherwise you will lose the variables of course.

If you leave out the outer select and just use the inner select, you see that there is no real magic happening, just simple if-then in MySQL.

Additional info, you can even modify this to measure times between In and Out.

The [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5d944/17) shows how it works, and [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5d944/18) gets the results. In your example you forgot the touple `128407, 30555, 30617, -1`

```
set @found4=0;
set @found5=0;
set @found45=0;
set @found46=0;
set @current45=0;

select first4, current45, first46, max(first5)
  from (
      select `date`, `time`, event, @found4:=if(event=4 and @found4=0, time+@found5 := 0, @found4) as first4, 
      @found45:=if(event=45 and @found4>0 and @found45=0,  time + @found46 := 0, @found45) as first45,
      @found46:=if(event=46 and @found4>0 and @found45>0 and @found46 = 0,  time + (@current45:=@found45) - @found45 + @found45 :=0, @found46) as first46,
      @current45 as current45,
      @found5:=if(event=5 and @found4>0 and @found46 > 0 and @found5 = 0, time + @found4:=0 + @found45 := 0 + @found46 := 0, @found5 ) as first5
      from t0 order by `date`, `time`
      ) as innersel where first4>0 and first46 > 0 group by first4, current45, first46;
```

This gives

```
first4  current45   first46     max(first5)
23327   24195       26370       27152
28407   30428       30449       0
28407   30514       30540       0
28407   30555       30617       0
```

as results.

I hope you see your "state machine" in the setting and resetting of the variables. I must add and subtract `@found45` in order to set `@current45`, but not to disturb `@found46`.

Comment: For me it seems to work [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5d944/1) and here you see how [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5d944/2). You have to add your 'day between ...` of course, into the inner where.

Comment: This is a nice solution, thanks! i've based the above solution on it. still need your help.

Comment: Are the 4 rows in my result what you want or what you not want? If not, explain the needed behaviour. I think my numbers exactly represent what you explain and you give as examples.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a php solution based on the answer of [flaschenpost](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2277620/flaschenpost) i know it's not a great one but it's close to what i need. still only one problem.

```
    $req="SELECT * FROM t0 WHERE date BETWEEN '2015-09-03' AND '2015-09-03' ORDER BY date, time, id";
    $q = $conn->prepare($req);
    $q->execute();

    $event1 = 0;
    $event2 = 0;
    $event3 = 0;
    $event4 = 0;
    while($r=$q->fetch()){

        if($r['event'] == 4 and $event1 == 0) {
            echo $r['time'] . ' - ' . $r['event'] . '<br>';
            $event1 = 1;
            $event2 = 0;
            $event3 = 0;
            $event4 = 0;
        }

        if($r['event'] == 45 and $event1 == 1) {
            echo $r['time'] . ' - ' . $r['event'] . '<br>';
            $event1 = 1;
            $event2 = 1;
            $event3 = 0;
            $event4 = 0;
        }

        if($r['event'] == 46 and $event1 == 1) {
            echo $r['time'] . ' - ' . $r['event'] . '<br>';
            $event1 = 1;
            $event2 = 1;
            $event3 = 1;
            $event4 = 0;
        }

        if($r['event'] == 5 and $event1 == 1 and $event2 == 1 and $event3 == 1) {
            echo $r['time'] . ' - ' . $r['event'] . '<br><br>';
            $event1 = 0;
            $event2 = 0;
            $event3 = 0;
            $event4 = 0;
        }
    }
```

The result is:

```
    23327 - 4      -> Start Event 1
    24195 - 45
    26370 - 46
    27152 - 5      -> End Event 1

    28407 - 4      -> Start Event 2
    30428 - 45
    30449 - 46      -> This must be considered the End of Event 2    
    30514 - 45      -> This must be considered the Start of Event 3
    30540 - 46      -> This must be considered the End of Event 3
    30555 - 45
    30617 - 46
    30631 - 45
    30687 - 46
    30723 - 45
    34059 - 46
    34073 - 45
    34479 - 46
    34499 - 5

    34660 - 4
    34665 - 45
    35007 - 46
    35009 - 45
    36505 - 45
    36505 - 46
    36525 - 5

    47085 - 4
```

As you can see there might be a case where we don't have events 4 and 5 so we must show only events 45 and 46.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I had to introduce variable "current45" to save last event 45, so if a "5" comes, I still know the last touple 45/46. The 46 must clear the variable for "first45", but before you should store it.

Comment: And _please_: if you have the events numerical, don't call your variables `event1` to `event4`, where 2 is 4 but 4 is 5 and 3 is 46. Leave that to Goethes Hexeneinmaleins.

Comment: So the event 46 at 30449 also ends the 4 of 28407, so the next line should not be `28407   30514       30540       0` but `0   30514       30540       0`? Or what?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by "Goethes Hexeneinmaleins" But Let me explain what i really am looking for because i'm so close, we have 4 events (4,45,46 and 5). each events must be in one line starting from 4 and ending with 5. But that's not always the case, there might be a case where we don't have event number 4 so we must only show events 0-45-46-5, there might be another case where we don't have event number 5 (4-45-46-0), etc...

Comment: L1 : 23327 - 24195 - 26370 - 27152
L2 : 28407 - 30428 - 30449 - 00000
L3 : 00000 - 30514 - 30540 - 00000

Comment: The problem is that your solutions seems not well-defined, or at least that you need look-ahead here. If an Event4 stays valid until the next event5, things are easy. If an event4 stays valid until next event46, everything is ok too. But the end of an event4 is event46, if next thing is event4 or event45, but the event4 stretches to next event5, if that comes before next event4 or event45 or event46. Please make sure you did not misunderstand the original problem. If this is the problem, you should try to find a good data structrure that is fit for thoses searches.